# Activate makeCopulaHead in Stanford CoreNLP parser

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to use Stanford CoreNLP Parser to parse a sentence with the flag "makeCopulaHead" activated.

In my file input.txt, I have the following sentence:

```
I am tall.
```

The objective is to not have a copula relation (cop) in the output dependency tree.

I tried:

```
java -cp "*" -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -makeCopulaHead -file input.txt
```

The .xml file contains cop relation :(

I also tried (a bug with xml-output: https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2013-January/002959.html ?):

```
java -cp "*" -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -makeCopulaHead -file input.txt -outputFormat text
```

But it's the same thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found out the solution, the correct line is:

```
java -cp "*" -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -parse.flags " -makeCopulaHead" -file input.txt
```

Don't forget the space in " -makeCopulaHead".