# Stanford NLP how is root of SemanticGraph determined

Tags: graph, root, stanford-nlp

I have question about **root** element of **SemanticGraph**. How is it specified(determined)? I am sure It doesn't need to be always a verb. I am trying to use the graph but I don't know what possible forms it can have.

**A rare black squirrel has become a regular visitor to a suburban garden.**

```
-> become/VBN (root)
  -> squirrel/NN (nsubj)
    -> A/DT (det)
    -> rare/JJ (amod)
    -> black/JJ (amod)
  -> has/VBZ (aux)
  -> visitor/NN (xcomp)
    -> a/DT (det)
    -> regular/JJ (amod)
  -> garden/NN (prep_to)
    -> a/DT (det)
    -> suburban/JJ (amod)
```

vs.

**Bill is an honest man.**

```
-> man/NN (root)
  -> Bill/NNP (nsubj)
  -> is/VBZ (cop)
  -> an/DT (det)
  -> honest/JJ (amod)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a while I found a solution to my problem. As I learned there are two types of ROOT elements. `Normal` verbs and verb to `BE`.

As it is written in Stanford typed dependencies manual (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf section 4.7) they are called Copula werbs and to avoid using other thing then verb in the root you need to use **-makeCopulaHead** flag.

How to add flag:

1. [Activate makeCopulaHead in Stanford CoreNLP parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525859/activate-makecopulahead-in-stanford-corenlp-parser)
2. Using java:

   ```
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("parse.flags", "-makeCopulaHead");
   ```

Result for **Bill is an honest man.**

```
-> is/VBZ (root)
  -> Bill/NNP (nsubj)
  -> man/NN (xcomp)
    -> an/DT (det)
    -> honest/JJ (amod)
```